# Inverse Function Theorem Question.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

The inverse function theorem is a general statement about finding local open sets and an inverse on those sets. The standard proof by Spivak doesn't tell you about the sizes of the sets.

A different proof using the contraction mapping theorem does using the norm of the differential, - is it possible to recover this estimate within Spivaks proof? Or is the result strictly stronger?

For clarity, I mean set containment with reference to balls or cubes. For example if we have a C^1 transformation F with nonzero jacobian where the differential is approximately equal to the identity on some set S, we can say that for a circle C contained in S, that F(C) contains a circle slightly smaller than C and is contained in a circle slightly larger than F(C).

Comment: For clarity, I mean set containment with reference to balls or cubes. For example if the differential is approximately equal to the identity on some set S, we can say that for a circle C contained in S, that F(C) contains a circle slightly smaller than C and is contained in a circle slightly larger than F(C).

Comment: please place your clarification in your question.